# Is walter white a selfish man?

Tags: breaking-bad

Is walter white a selfish man? Asking because at the last episode, he says to his wife 'I enjoyed it' i.e selling drugs, killing people. What is the meaning of it?

Comment: Related (if not even duplicate): [“I did it for me. I liked it” - Is this a lie to convince Skyler?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/q/20045/49)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Walter satisfied his ego becoming what anyone wouldn't dreamt of.
The person behind the druglord mask was fed up with failures and cancer phase gave the extra-ordinary courage to the introverted guy and take the extra mile - 'you can do whatever measures to guard your family'.

But at one point when he says to Skyler - 'I'm the guy who knocks' he elevates himself to a undisputable GOD. Point to note - he was recovering from his cancer at that time.

Later during the all alone phase hiding for his life, in nowhere he realised what he has became and uttered - 'I enjoyed it'.

The best of deciding Good or Bad is to 'Realise' which side you really on.